# Python: How to chronologically sort by date and find any gaps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I searched for an answer, but couldn't find!

I have a dataframe that looks like:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cust_Name' : ['APPT1', 'APPT1','APPT2','APPT2'],
               'Move_In':['2013-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-02-04','2019-02-19'],
               'Move_Out':['2019-01-31','','2019-02-15','']})
```

I am looking to find a way to calculate the vacancy. 
APPT1 was occupied from 2013-02-01 to 2019-01-31 and, again from the next day 2019-02-01. So the vacancy for APPT1 is 0 and is currently occupied.
APPT2 was occupied from 2019-02-04 to 2019-02-15 and, again from 2019-02-19. So the vacancy for APPT2 is 2 business days and is currently occupied.
NaT: means currently occupied or currently occupied.

TIA

Comment: What is expected output? New column? Another DataFrame?

Comment: Expected output is a New column

Comment: Can you add expected output to question? I think numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cust_Name': ['APPT1', 'APPT1','APPT2','APPT2'],
    'Move_In': ['2013-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-02-04','2019-02-19'],
    'Move_Out': ['2019-01-31','','2019-02-15','']
})
df['Move_In'] = df['Move_In'].astype('datetime64')
df['Move_Out'] = df['Move_Out'].astype('datetime64')
df['Prev_Move_Out'] = df['Move_Out'].shift()
```

```
    Cust_Name   Move_In     Move_Out    Prev_Move_Out
0   APPT1   2013-02-01  2019-01-31      NaT
1   APPT1   2019-02-01  NaT             2019-01-31
2   APPT2   2019-02-04  2019-02-15      NaT
3   APPT2   2019-02-19  NaT             2019-02-15
```

```py
def calculate_business_day_vacancy(df):
  try:
      return len(pd.date_range(start=df['Prev_Move_Out'], end=df['Move_In'], freq='B')) - 2
  except ValueError:
      # Consider instead running the function only on rows that do not contain NaT.
      return 0

df['Vacancy_BDays'] = df.apply(calculate_business_day_vacancy, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
Cust_Name   Move_In     Move_Out    Prev_Move_Out   Vacancy_BDays
0   APPT1   2013-02-01  2019-01-31      NaT         0
1   APPT1   2019-02-01  NaT             2019-01-31  0
2   APPT2   2019-02-04  2019-02-15      NaT         0
3   APPT2   2019-02-19  NaT             2019-02-15  1
```

Note that there is only one *Business Day* vacancy between 15 Feb 2019 and 19 Feb 2019.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks @ulmefors